How should I frame a question about the soundness of a particular objection to an argument?
I came across a particular argument and associated objection in philosophy of the mind. Both the argument and the objection can't be sound, but I can't find where either goes wrong. I thought I'd come here for some help.
I'm new to Philosophy SE, so I'm not sure how to best frame this question to fit with the norms of this site. Asking "where does this objection go wrong" or "is this objection sound" would seem way too open-ended for most of the other sites I'm part of on SE. Is there another way to frame it that would work better? Here are some options:

Asking a more specific question that I think gets to the heart of the disagreement. But, the problem might be somewhere else than where I think it is and this more specific question might not get at the real problem.
Asking if any philosophers have already addressed this point. It's in a fairly well-known book (Chalmer's The Conscious Mind), so I imagine someone's responded, I just can't find it.
Asking the more open-ended "where does the argument or objection go wrong?"
Something else?


There are lots of those types of questions if you search around. The format “is this argument flawed” or anything similar usually doesn’t get downvoted or closed, it’s a recurrent question type.

Please be sure to add enough context: what assumptions you’re working with, and at least some of the considerations that make you think the argument fails. This will give you better answers
